# PHP - linebreak in String does not work

Tags: php

I have an array with strings. The strings shall have line breaks. My code produces the 
 as text not as tag. How can I manage to create a 
 tag in the HTML that creates a line break?

```
<?php return array(
  ....
  'subtitle'    => nl2br("My Sentence shall have a \n line break right there") ,
 ...
);


 <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($CONFIG['subtitle']); ?></title>
```

Result

```
   My Sentence shall have a <br> line break right there
```

Comment: what is your question? Can you try to be more explicit?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer updated my question

Comment: You do know what [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) does, don't you? If you have to use htmlspecialchars(), do it ___before___ the nl2br()

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` translates all `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, rendering your html tags to not be interpreted by the browser anymore. If you want to have an actual `<br>` tag in there, avoid `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: `<title>` tag doesn't have a line break or i am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most answers have suggested, remove the `htmlspecialchars` section. Also, your `\n` should be replaced with `\r\n` for environments that don't recognize only the `\n`. The updated code should look like below:

```
<?php return array(
  ....
  'subtitle'    => nl2br("My Sentence shall have a \r\n line break right there") ,
 ...
);


 <title><?php echo $CONFIG['subtitle']; ?></title>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The htmlspecialchars does not do

> "\n" => "<br/>"

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

> The translations performed are:
>
> ```
> '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
> '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
> "'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
> '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
> '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
> ```

Edit:  As the comment below says, http://php.net/nl2br is the best solution.

You need to use a str replace or regex replace or something:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Or `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($string));`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with:

```
<?php return array(
  ....
  'subtitle'    => "My Sentence shall have a \n line break right there",
 ...
);


 <title><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($CONFIG['subtitle'])); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the `htmlspecialchars` you get the desired behaviour

```
 echo $CONFIG['subtitle'];
```

It replaces your tags so they can be printed in html, and you dont want that

Comment: He wants to replace \n with <br/>, your solution does not do that.

Comment: @mikeb the issue is not what that "he wants to replace \n with <br/>" (hes already doing that with nl2br), and therefore my solution does not do that. My reply provides a solution to his problem